# How to allow to select only one dynamically generated radio box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to create a back-end for a contest page..By default here are two input boxes with a radio button stating which one is true and an add button which dynamically generates the input boxes and radio buttons through javascript..I have given same "Name" to the two radio boxes which are by default available and the ones which are dynamically generated..I have used array to name them..Still when i select one radio box still i am able to select other radio button as well..I want to unable this option..kindly help..

Here is the javascript code for dynamically generated input box and radio box

```
var doc_index = <?php echo $fans; ?>;//rows - 1

    function AddDocRow(){

        doc_index ++;
        index = doc_index;

        doc_html = "<tr id='doc_" + index + "'>" +
            "<td>"+ (index+1) +"</td>" +
            "<td>" +

            "<input type='text' class='span12'  id='option[" + index + "]' name='option[" + index + "]' placeholder='' />" +

            "</td>" +
            "<td><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='RemoveDocRow(" + index + ")'><i class='icon-remove red'></i></a></td>"+
            "<td>"+

            "<label>"+
            "<input type='radio' name='right[" + index + "]' value='1' /><span class='lbl'></span>"+
            "</label>"+

            "</td>"+
            "</tr>";


        $('table#doc_rows tbody').append(doc_html);
        //number ++;
    }
```

---

And here is the code for the default two options..

```
                                 <td>
                                    <label>
                                        <?php $check=($r['is_true']==1) ? 'checked="checked"' :''; ?>
                                        <input type="radio" <?php echo $check;  ?> name="right[<?php echo $counter1; ?>]" value="1" id="radio" /><span class="lbl"></span>
                                    </label>
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 4):

Two or more radio button need to have the same EXACT name to give them the "unique" selection option. Your radios name are Dynamic, with different Name for each one.

Comment: hello thanks for the reply i could have gave unique name but then it wont serve the purpose to store the correct answer in database

Comment: That's a question solvable in some ways... you can as example pass different data as values and then work on it, you can insert a Javascript system to save the data Too, but to have the "radio" unique you need to give them the same exact name.

Answer (score 0):

The name of radio should be `unique` ie, what are the radio button which you want group.

`"<input type='radio' name='radioGroupName' value='1' /><span class='lbl'></span>"+`

You can apply index logic for id attribute.

Comment: hello thanks for the reply i could have gave unique name but then it wont serve the purpose to store the correct answer in database

Answer (score 0):

The radio buttons do not have the same `name` - they must have the same name in order to be grouped as the same set of radio buttons.

I believe simply changing the name of each to `name="right"` should suffice

Comment: hello thanks for the reply i could have gave unique name but then it wont serve the purpose to store the correct answer in database

Answer (score 0):

change

```
"<input type='radio' name='right[" + index + "]' value='1' /><span class='lbl'></span>"
```

to

```
"<input type='radio' name='right' id='right[" + index + "]' value='1' /><span class='lbl'></span>"
```

or

```
"<input type='radio' name='right' value='+ index  +' /><span class='lbl'></span>"
```

this way you can give them same name, and differentiate between the two by id

Comment: hello thanks for the reply i could have gave unique name but then it wont serve the purpose to store the correct answer in database

Comment: use your index variable in place of value that can be more helpful, name of radio button has to be same in case of single selection between the two

Comment: or add whole code so we can see where you are getting problem to get the value